# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'props' of undefined in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using `redux` in my application where I am trying to do increment and decrement.

/actions/index.js

```
export const INCREMENT = "SCORE_INCREMENT";
export const DECREMENT = "SCORE_DECREMENT";

const scoreAction = {
  increment() {
    return {
      type: INCREMENT
    };
  },

  decrement() {
    return {
      type: DECREMENT
    };
  }
};

export default scoreAction;
```

/reducers/index.js

```
import * as actions from "../actions";

const scoreReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.INCREMENT:
      return state + 1;
    case actions.DECREMENT:
      return state - 1;
    default:
      break;
  }
};

export default scoreReducer;
```

index.js

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import scoreReducer from "./reducers";

let store = createStore(scoreReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import RoundedButton from "./RoundedButton";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { scoreAction } from "./actions/index";
import * as actions from "./actions/index";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      score: 0
    };
    this.clickitem = this.clickitem.bind(this);
  }

  clickitem(user) {
    var url = "http://localhost:4000/generate-random";
    fetch(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        var computer = data.item;
        console.log("------------------------------------");
        console.log(user + computer);
        console.log("------------------------------------");
        if (
          (user === "Rock" && computer === "Scissors") ||
          (user === "Paper" && computer === "Rock") ||
          (user === "Scissors" && computer === "Paper")
        ) {
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          console.log("User won!!");
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          this.props.increment();
        } else if (user === computer) {
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          console.log("Tie");
          console.log("------------------------------------");
        } else {
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          console.log("Computer won!!");
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          this.props.decrement();
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { store } = this.context;
    console.log("------------------------------------");
    console.log(store);
    console.log("------------------------------------");
    return (
      <div className="AppTitle">
        <b>Score:</b>
        <div>
          <RoundedButton text="Rock" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
          <RoundedButton text="Paper" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
          <RoundedButton text="Scissors" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProp(state) {
  return { score: state };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProp, actions)(App);
```

I am getting an error

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18380:15
  18377 |       console.log("------------------------------------");
  18378 |       console.log("Computer won!!");
  18379 |       console.log("------------------------------------");
> 18380 |       this.props.decrement();
        |           ^  18381 |     }
  18382 |   });
  18383 | }
View source
```

Can anyone hint me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: `this` actually does not refer to the component here.

Comment: @wesley6j you are correct. I used arrow function now I am getting this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605211/unhandled-rejection-typeerror-cannot-read-property-props-of-undefined-in-re#comment76197535_44605266

Comment: Try this.props.scoreAction.decrement

Comment: @VivekN I tried but same issue `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'increment' of undefined`

Comment: And inside your clickItem function do this var that=this; and then access that.props.scoreAction.decrement()

Comment: @Williams did you try what I said? That should solve your problem

Comment: @VivekN I tried that also, this also didn't work

Comment: What error are you getting after you did what I mentioned in my comments?

Comment: @VivekN `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'increment' of undefined
(anonymous function)
D:\ReactJS\rock-paper-scissors-app\src\App.js:42
39 | console.log("------------------------------------");
40 | console.log("User won!!");
41 | console.log("------------------------------------");
> 42 | that.props.scoreAction.increment();
43 | } else if (user === computer) {
44 | console.log("------------------------------------");
45 | console.log("Tie");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible please change your action creator function to as follows:-

```
export const INCREMENT = "SCORE_INCREMENT";
export const DECREMENT = "SCORE_DECREMENT";


  export function increment() {
    return {
      type: INCREMENT
    };
  }

  export function decrement() {
    return {
      type: DECREMENT
    };
  }
```

Let me know if this works.

Also inside your clickItem function put this as the first line:-

```
var that = this;
```

Then access increment and decrement using

```
that.props.decrement()
```

Comment: `that.props.decrement()` - this calls action creators and update the state with the help of reducers. I see mostly examples are using dispatcher kinda. can you please help whats that ? how that works if I do same thing with that ? or dispatch action is old approach ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like context problem. Try to use arrow functions in fetch.

```
  fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        var computer = data.item;
        console.log("------------------------------------");
        console.log(user + computer);
        console.log("------------------------------------");
        if (
          (user === "Rock" && computer === "Scissors") ||
          (user === "Paper" && computer === "Rock") ||
          (user === "Scissors" && computer === "Paper")
        ) {
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          console.log("User won!!");
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          this.props.increment();
        } else if (user === computer) {
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          console.log("Tie");
          console.log("------------------------------------");
        } else {
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          console.log("Computer won!!");
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          this.props.decrement();
        }
      });
```

Comment: Now I am getting `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _this2.props.decrement is not a function`

Comment: Using arrow functions helped me in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problem the first one is that you are not binding the function in which you are calling the decrement function.

Secondly, decrement is not directly available as a prop to the component but its is inside actions

Third you need to dispatch your action. You can change your code to the following

```
import scoreAction from "./actions/index";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      score: 0
    };
    this.clickitem = this.clickitem.bind(this);
  }

  clickitem (user)  {
    var url = "http://localhost:4000/generate-random";
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        var computer = data.item;
        console.log("------------------------------------");
        console.log(user + computer);
        console.log("------------------------------------");
        if (
          (user === "Rock" && computer === "Scissors") ||
          (user === "Paper" && computer === "Rock") ||
          (user === "Scissors" && computer === "Paper")
        ) {
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          console.log("User won!!");
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          this.props.increment();
        } else if (user === computer) {
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          console.log("Tie");
          console.log("------------------------------------");
        } else {
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          console.log("Computer won!!");
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          this.props.decrement();
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { store } = this.context;
    console.log("------------------------------------");
    console.log(store);
    console.log("------------------------------------");
    return (
      <div className="AppTitle">
        <b>Score:</b>
        <div>
          <RoundedButton text="Rock" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
          <RoundedButton text="Paper" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
          <RoundedButton text="Scissors" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProp(state) {
  return { score: state };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return bindActionCreators({decrement: scoreAction.decrement, increment:  scoreAction.increment}, dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProp, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Also change he action file to

```
export const INCREMENT = "SCORE_INCREMENT";
export const DECREMENT = "SCORE_DECREMENT";

const scoreAction = {
  increment: function() {
    return {
      type: INCREMENT
    };
  },

  decrement: function() {
    return {
      type: DECREMENT
    };
  }
};

export default scoreAction;
```

Comment: I am getting   Line 76:  'bindActionCreators' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: You need to import, do it with `import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'`

Comment: I am getting still same `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'decrement' of undefined
(anonymous function)
D:\ReactJS\rock-paper-scissors-app\src\App.js:50
  47 |         console.log("------------------------------------");
  48 |         console.log("Computer won!!");
  49 |         console.log("------------------------------------");
> 50 |         this.props.actions.decrement();
  51 |       }
  52 |     });
  53 | }`

Comment: did you use arrow functions to bind the callback

Comment: check the updated answer, scoreActions was a default export so used it differently

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146944/discussion-between-williams-and-shubham-khatri).

Comment: Thanks a lot Shubham +1

Comment: can you specify where you use score from props here