# TypeError: Cannot read property 'score' of undefined in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am integrating `redux` in my application, where I am trying to increment/decrement score and updating match status on increment and decrement.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import RoundedButton from "./RoundedButton";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import * as actions from "./actions/index";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      score: 0,
      status: ""
    };
    this.clickitem = this.clickitem.bind(this);
  }

  clickitem(user) {
    var url = "http://localhost:4000/generate-random";
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        var computer = data.item;
        if (
          (user === "Rock" && computer === "Scissors") ||
          (user === "Paper" && computer === "Rock") ||
          (user === "Scissors" && computer === "Paper")
        ) {
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          console.log("User won!!");
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          this.props.increment();
        } else if (user === computer) {
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          console.log("Tie");
          console.log("------------------------------------");
        } else {
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          console.log("Computer won!!");
          console.log("------------------------------------");
          this.props.decrement();
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="AppTitle">
        <b>Score: {this.props.score}</b>
        <div>
          <RoundedButton text="Rock" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
          <RoundedButton text="Paper" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
          <RoundedButton text="Scissors" clickitem={this.clickitem} />
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { score: state.score, status: state.status };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
```

actions/index.js

```
export const INCREMENT = "SCORE_INCREMENT";
export const DECREMENT = "SCORE_DECREMENT";

let score = 0;

export function increment() {
  return { type: INCREMENT, score: score++ };
}

export function decrement() {
  return { type: DECREMENT, score: score++ };
}
```

reducers/index.js

```
import * as actions from "../actions";

const initialState = { score: 0, status: "" };

const scoreReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.INCREMENT:
      return { score: action.score, status: "You won!" };
    case actions.DECREMENT:
      return { score: action.score, status: "Computer won!" };
    default:
      break;
  }
};

export default scoreReducer;
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import "./index.css";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import scoreReducer from "./reducers";

let store = createStore(scoreReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

I am getting below error. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong ?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'score' of undefined
Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps]
D:\ReactJS\rock-paper-scissors-app\src\App.js:68
  65 | }
  66 | 
  67 | function mapStateToProps(state) {
> 68 |   return { score: state.score, status: state.status };
  69 | }
  70 | 
  71 | export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
View compiled
```

Comment: Your initial reducer state `{}` defined as a default parameter of your reducer is missing an initial state containing your `score` & `status` properties.

Comment: can you guide me how to initialize initial state ?

Comment: You could for example replace the default parameter by a variable like `(state = initialState, action)` and `initialState` being an object like `{ score: 0, status: '' }`.

Comment: @Williams your default state should be { score: 0, status: what ever you want to keep}

Comment: @VivekN Is it correct `const scoreReducer = (state = { score: 0, status: "" }, action) => {` ? I am facing same problem still

Comment: I would suggest initializing it before hand as const initialState={ score: 0, status: '' ''}
And then do state = initialState

Comment: Do this inside your scoreReducer

Comment: @HiDeo I did, but still same error

Comment: Your default Condition should return initialState

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the error because when no action is fired you are not returning anything.

From your reducer you need to return the state by default

```
import * as actions from "../actions";

const scoreReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.INCREMENT:
      return { score: action.score, status: "You won!" };
    case actions.DECREMENT:
      return { score: action.score, status: "Computer won!" };
    default:
      return state
      break;
  }
};

export default scoreReducer;
```

Comment: Not eagle eyes, Its because I have come across this situation myself and had to struggle a lot. So had a first look for the same. Anyways glad your problem is solved

Comment: If you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605211/unhandled-rejection-typeerror-cannot-read-property-props-of-undefined-in-re It was working without default state how ?

Comment: Yes @Shubham is right. You are missing default return here

Comment: so that worked there because you were assigning only state and it returned you undefined initially, now here you are using state.score which will fail becaue state is undefined and you are getting a property from it.